# External hard drive unreadable after copy

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

So I had a macbook pro on loan from school. I had to turn it in yesterday so what I did was copy all the files that where on there to an external hard drive. After that I tried too copy the applications folder to the same external hard drive. I cancelled it at some point which didn't work so I force closed it.

I ended up with a directory with a loading bar in it and a cross in the left corner. I figured this was an apple thing and I would be able to see the files that did copy until the cancel on a windows machine. I continued and erased the macbook pro completely went home wanted to but the backup on my pc and got a error saying that the drive was corrupted and needed to be formatted...

I really need the files that where stored on it. Does anyone have any idea how to get them back in such a manner that the directory structure and meta data will be intact?

EDIT:

I ran testdisk and I got the following partitions
[image]

Comment: So, you have backed-up your files from your Mac, and then tried to use the same external harddrive on PC, and it says the drive was corrupted? just to clear things out for better judgment.

Comment: @ISR5 yeahh that is what happened. I'm thinking that it is because of the cancelled copy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: @DavidPostill not a duplicate, as of this system compatible issue.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that I did set it to NTFS before I started copying the files to the external hard drive

Comment: I don't think this is a platform issue (Mac vs PC), you just need to go down the standard file recovery road. This should be treated no differently.

Comment: I think the issue is that the files are still there but the entery to it is broken. Figured there should be a way to fix that. I tried running "TestDisk" but it automaticly select that there are non partitions. So I'm not sure how to cntinue

Answer (score 0):

Your hard drive was formatted with Mac file system (HFS or FAT), and since you now need to use it on PC, you will need to convert its file system format to **NTFS** in order to be readable by Windows.

**To Convert your hard drive file system to NTFS:**

1. Open the Command Prompt (With administrative privileges).
2. In the Command Prompt, type  **convert x: /fs:ntfs** and then press Enter.

*(Change the **x** to your external hard drive letter)*

After you're done, just go to the hard drive and try to access it.

**NOTE: Converting file system format won't cause any data loss.**

Comment: I tried doin this but it says that the current format is ntfs

Comment: @NoSixties probably the MBR files are corrupted. IF so, you need to use a third party tool to recover the drive partitions and fix them. I use one myself and it's pretty useful tools.

Comment: I ran testdisk and got the following partitions(see edit for screenshot)

Comment: @NoSixties run another test using Intel option (first option).

Comment: Thats what I did and these were the results. When I run chkdsk I get an error saying that the mft table is damaged

Comment: @NoSixties you have to continue the process, after the analyzer is done, do a quick search then recover the corrupted partitions after that. Try to find a guide into how to use it to help you recover it.